# Promise Resolution after $http success is getting mixed up

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise, angularjs-http

I have created a factory, to handle all my http related calls. It returns following inline code:

```
    return {
        get: function (opts) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var def = defaultOptions(HttpMethod.Get);
            $.extend(def, opts);

            $http({ method: 'get', url: config.remoteServiceName + def.url }).then(function (result, status, header) {
                def.success(deferred, { data: result });
            }, function (data) {
                def.error(deferred, data);
            });

            return deferred.promise;
        },
        post: function (opts) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var def = defaultOptions(HttpMethod.Post);
            $.extend(def, opts);

            $http.post(config.remoteServiceName + def.url, def.data).then(function (result) {
                def.success(deferred, result);
            }, function (data) {
                def.error(deferred, data);
            });

            return deferred.promise;
        },
        remove: function (opts) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var def = defaultOptions(HttpMethod.Delete);
            $.extend(def, opts);

            $http({ method: 'delete', url: config.remoteServiceName + def.url }).then(function (result) {
                def.success(deferred, result);
            }, function (data) {
                def.error(deferred, data);
            });

            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
```

Now, when i am making the calls, if there are few parallel calls being made, all promise resolution is getting mixed up. I am getting the resultset from one request in another's resolution.

Not able to solve the problem. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I guess defaultOptions always returns the same object so you will get multiple calls for the last callback set as you're overriding the object each time you call one of your functions

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue. Any resolution?

Comment: @hofnarwillie Issue was not of parallel calls. It was somewhere else. JS model for ajax execution works fine, and no issue with $http either. We were using WebAPI as backend, and some of our global filters had state, which got altered on each call. Hence the data was mixed up. No issue on client end.

Comment: @sandeep You should mark the issue as resolved then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was not of parallel calls. It was somewhere else. JS model for ajax execution works fine, and no issue with $http either. We were using WebAPI as backend, and some of our global filters had state, which got altered on each call. Hence the data was mixed up. No issue on client end.

Thanks everyone